# how to specify the retry mechanism in htmlunit's webclient

Tags: java, httpclient, htmlunit

I just want to adjust the retry time in htmlunit's webClient. But it seems that there is no such a configuration.
So I want to know how to do this? or how to access the httpClient behind the webClient(it seems that webClient uses apache's httpClient to do the underlying HTTP operation)

Comment: Sorry but for me it is not really clear what goal you have. Can you please add some more details about your case to the question. Outside of this HtmlUnit is open source (hosted on GitHub). It is easy to look at the source....

Comment: what I want to do is adjust the HtmlUnit's retry time when its http request is failed. And I have no idea whether this operation should be executed on HtmlUnit's WebClient or on the WebClient's HttpClient.
Yes I knows that I maybe can access my goal by search in the HtmlUnit's source code. But I think that should exists a standard operation(or a recommended operation, but I can't find it through HtmlUnit's official documentation) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far there is no support to configure this. Please open a issue /feature request and describe your needs. Will try to support that.

As HtmlUnit tries to mimic real browsers as possible it will be great if you can point to any information how real browsers handling this situations.